# Javascript Hover Issue on an Image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an effect with javascript.

**Effect:**

When I click on any menu it is to show the active Image which is **symb1.png**. Following is my code:

**Css:**

```
<style>
    li{display:inline;padding:0 10px; z-index:-1;}
    .red{ background-image:url('symb1.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
</style>
```

**Html in Body tag**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="red" onClick="selected(this)">MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="selected(this)">MENU 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="selected(this)">MENU 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Finally the Javasript code before closing **html body** tag:

```
<script>
    function selected(obj){
        var lilist = document.getElementById('menu');
        var alist = lilist.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (i=0; i<alist.length; i++ )
        {
           alist[i].className="";
        }
        obj.className="red";
    }
</script>
```

It's working fine with the text MENU, MENU 1, MENU 2 etc. But If I put any Image instead of text then it doesn't work. It doesn't show the active image. Why does this happen?

**Update:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
li{display:inline;padding:0 10px; z-index:-1;}
.red{ background-image:url(symb1.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#" class="red">MENU</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="selected(this)">MENU 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="selected(this)">MENU 2</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
$('ul li a').click(function(){
 $('ul li a').removeClass('red');
$(this).addClass('red'); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you opposed to using the jquery library?

Comment: @JonHarding I'm new in Javascript. it's my Learning time..

Comment: your probably could very well be a bad path to your image. I'd certainly recommend getting familiar with the jquery library

Comment: @JonHarding learning jQuery without proper knowledge od Javascript leads to horrible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are open to jquery but here is a very simple solution.  Also, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Pd3/) so you can see it in action:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li a').click(function(){
        $('ul li a').removeClass('red');
        $(this).addClass('red'); 
    });
});
```

The rest of your code stays the same.  Of course you'll need to include the jquery library in the head of your document:

```
<script src="//http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I saw your link. It's show Red Color on click. But I'm trying to show a image instead of Red Color. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes, this is just switching adding/removing the class, you can change the 'red' class to include reference to your image.

Comment: Is your image in the same folder as your HTML file? If not you'll need to revisit the path or your image.  Also add quotes around the path

Comment: `element.className = '';` is the same like remove all classes from element. `className` affect `classList` and vice versa.

Comment: It should be the same: *classList is a convenient alternative to accessing an element's list of classes as a space-delimited string via element.className.* see the reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

Comment: @JanTuron - I'm showing a jquery solution, there isn't a function for `.className()`

Comment: Oh, yes - the jQuery is doing it the old-fashined way by modifying className, see the source of 1.9.1 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js - however, today you can conveniently use classList, see the browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=classList - therefore jQuery is not an optimal solution at all, IMHO - especially when jQuery 2.0+ drops support for IE<10.

Comment: @JonHarding I just updated my code. Why it doesn't work now ?

Comment: @AlexMojum your code works well, just a bit unexpected way - see my answer

Comment: @AlexMojum It's hard to say why your CSS selector isn't showing the image without knowing your solution structure (folders). But valid CSS should solve it.

Comment: @Alex, Place it in your own jsfiddle. Everything you currently have.